# Error in Grep regex

Tags: regex, grep

I have written following regex in grep command to find all the catch statements for SQLException in a directory containing java files.

```
catch\s{0,}\(s{0,}SQLException
```

it is giving "grep: Unmatched ( or (" error. This regex is working fine on RegExr.com. What is the issue with this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `\s`, you need to specify `-P` option (to allow Perl regular expression):

```
grep -P 'catch\s{0,}\(\s{0,}SQLException'
```

BTW, you can use `*` instead of `{0,}`.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` uses `BRE` by default and `\(` becomes start of a captured group (unescaped `(` is taken literally).

You can use this `grep` with extended regex mode `-E`:

```
grep -E 'catch[[:blank:]]*\([[:blank:]]*SQLException' file.log
```

Comment: Yes indeed, space came due to copy/paste of one word. Fixed now, thanks.